# How to build a function that finds all integers between two values from two different lists using python?

Tags: python

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
output1=list(range(1,4))
output2=list(range(2,5))
output3=list(range(3,6))
```

How to build a function that takes first value  from a list and the first value from another list and finds all possible numbers between the two and repeat it till end of values and saves the output of every range as a different variable using python?

Comment: Use `zip(a, b)` to loop through both lists in parallel. And in your loop create a range for each pair of inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you ?

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
result=[ range(min(num1,num2), max(num1,num2)) for num1, num2 in zip(a,b)]

for element in result:
    print(*element)
```

Comment: `c, d` should be `num1, num2`